Changing the code so that the gradient animation only applies to the top 15% of the page
I got this code through a CSS animated gradient and I was wondering if there's a way to make sure only the top 15% of the page has the animated gradient, while the rest of the page stays black? Thanks! I'm new to CSS, and I'm working on a third-party Notion customization platform that's pretty complicated, so the less HTML I work with for this problem, I would appreciate it!
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000; /* Black background for the entire body */
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%; /* Upper 15% of the page */
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #eb5666, #e4c545, #ff8c4c, #0b1215);
    background-size: 800% 800%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 55s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 55s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 55s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}


I asked ChatGPT for help, and it gave me this but it didn't work. I was wondering if there's any way to do the 15:85 situation.
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000; /* Black background for the entire body */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.page-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh; /* Upper 15% of the page */
    position: relative;
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #eb5666, #e4c545, #ff8c4c, #0b1215);
    background-size: 800% 800%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 55s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 55s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 55s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

/* The remaining part of the page */
.black-section {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #000;
}


if there's a way to make sure only the top 15% of the page has the animated gradient, while the rest of the page stays black - I copied your CSS word for word and added a div with a class of page and it works, only the top 15% of the page is the animated gradient and the other 85% is black. Perhaps you can add a snippet that reproduces the issue?

What does your HTML look like?  Assuming .page is a block box and not an inline box what you have originally should work just fine if I'm understanding what you're after.

It's possible I'm getting confused by your nomencliture. Is .page definitely a child of .page-container because if so I can't see why this doesn't work OK (but 'normally' I might think of something with class .page being, well, the whole page).
